# iframe and save content

Tags: php, javascript

Hi i have working script saving content from editor works in iframe to input hidden, and geting data from post array. But if i want send in framework, not working.

I tried to insert a hidden field with formlarza model, using the concatenating and outside the function. unfortunately does not work, but if you send out PHP framework, it works.

```
window.onload = function()
{                      
    document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){ 

    var text = document.getElementById('text'); text.value = Editor.body.innerHTML; } 
}


<iframe id="textbox"  name="textbox"></iframe><br />
<input type="hidden" id="text" name="text" />
```

Editor is defined in window.onload function, is fine but dont work when i use index.php and router. i sending form to adress admin.php?module=news&action=add

Script site: http://cstruter.com/blog/45

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but one thing that jumps out at me is that you've got an extra closing bracket (closed at end of line 2, then on a separate line).